# Build Error with yaml Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

i have tried to automate my pipeline, so configured azure pipeline manually over yaml. all task were successfully executed except last one.

last task is about to execute sql migration script in the database 'demodb'

```
- task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'sqlserviceConnection' 
        AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
        ServerName: 'demodb.database.windows.net'
        DatabaseName: 'demodb'
        deployType: 'SqlTask'
     SqlFile:'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\publish\SQL\migrate.sql'
        IpDetectionMethod: AutoDetect
```

that is the error i got:

> The specified schema name "xxx@xxx" either does not exist or you do
> not have permission to use it.

task highlights:

- sqlserviceConnection : service connection
- SqlFile : database migration script would be executed if pipeline
  successfully runs.

content of migrate.sql

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[__EFMigrationsHistory]') IS NULL
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [__EFMigrationsHistory] (
        [MigrationId] nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
        [ProductVersion] nvarchar(32) NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK___EFMigrationsHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId])
    );
END;
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210714144330_init')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [Users] (
        [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
        [BusinessPhones] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [DisplayName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [GivenName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [JobTitle] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [Mail] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [MobilePhone] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [OfficeLocation] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [PreferredLanguage] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [Surname] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        [UserPrincipalName] nvarchar(max) NULL,
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Users] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
    );
END;
GO

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [__EFMigrationsHistory] WHERE [MigrationId] = N'20210714144330_init')
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [__EFMigrationsHistory] ([MigrationId], [ProductVersion])
    VALUES (N'20210714144330_init', N'5.0.8');
END;
GO

COMMIT;
GO
```

what i did:

- created sql server
- created aad user
- assigned user aad as adb_admin in database 'demodb'
- created app service 'demoapp'
- registered the app service in aad
- added demoapp to aad

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by creating a schema in target database. also i granted aad user a permission to access that schema

```
CREATE SCHEMA MCMO 
AUTHORIZATION MCMO_Contributor
```